# what variable i can use instead of shared?

Tags: .net, asp.net, variables, shared

I have the following variable which creates problem when i use multiples instance of the same web form. Could you please let me know how i could what variables other than shared i can use to achieve this purpose?

```
Public strRoleType As String = String.Empty
Protected Shared isAreaSelected As Integer = 0
Protected Shared isStoreSelected As Integer = 0
Protected Shared isHeadOfficeSelected As Integer = 0
Protected Shared isRegionSelected As Integer = 0
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. 

Can you explain a little bit better what the problem is and/or what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: You shouldn't be using shared variables in ASP.NET like this (if it's on a per user basis) because it will affect everything application wide. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i had a session conflict problem in my web form hence i changed all the session variables to shared variables ..this is still again a problem.. what you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: In asp.net there isn't many cases where you want anything to be shared (or static in c#). Your default should be to not make it shared and think twice before making anything shared.

Comment: Please refer the link .. this is the exact problem i am facing : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514534/guessess-of-my-session-value-conflicts

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `Shared` and everything should be fine.

Comment: nope... when i removed shared .the the form is not working as expeected

Comment: Please refer the link .. this is the exact problem i am facing : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514534/guessess-of-my-session-value-conflicts

Comment: I read your post and I think you are very, very confused about the way that ASP.NET works when multiple people are looking at the site at the same time. I don't understand why you are using a combination of page variables and session variables, and since your application consists of only one .aspx, page variables are plenty appropriate (otherwise use session variables). That is, use one or the other, and you don't need 'shared' in your application.

Comment: but i remove the shared keywords from the variable declaration. the web form is not at all bypassing the 3rd page when i select any value in the first page..so whats wrong there?

Comment: @SmartestVEGA, I think you are missing the fact that the web is stateless.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot of work but it creates form level storage

For each of your shared variables convert it to a property on the WebForm. Then store the values in the ViewState

```
'default to 0 if blank, else convert to int
Public Property IsAreaSelected() As Integer
    Get
        Return If(ViewState("IsAreaSelected") Is Nothing, 0, Cint(ViewState("IsAreaSelected")))
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        ViewState("IsAreaSelected") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

This way the values stay with the page.

Please note I coded this up on the fly and not in VS so you may have to tweak it.